# On-device Google Drive for Desktop folder access between multiple users

Tags: windows-10, sync, google-drive-file-stream

Me and a couple of colleagues are using Google Drive for Desktop to keep a single folder synchronized between our desktops.

For context, we're using [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSWSj.png) client.

Our setup is slightly complicated, and maybe just a little stupid, but it works. Here it is:

- The folder is *on my hard drive* (I own it) and is being synced to Google Drive into my "My PC" folder. We'll call it **"Folder A"**
- The folder is shared through Google Drive to my colleagues using their emails
- Then we synced one of *their* desktop's folders to *their* Google Drive. We'll call this one **"Folder B"**
- In Google Drive, we placed a shortcut pointing to Folder A inside of Folder B (the 'create shortcut' tool in Google Drive)
- This shortcut was synced to their device, which can now be accessed as if it was on their own hard drive (the folder opens in File Explorer, where all contents are visible and can be edited as if it were a normal folder)

We have a total of three people with this folder (2 colleagues and myself).
I technically have multiple questions:

- Since the folder is actually on my hard drive[note 1], if my device can't sync the folder for some reason (such as if I don't have internet) and my colleagues work with files inside that folder, what happens?
- If I'm offline, will the two of them be "out of sync", or will they stay in sync with each other, regardless of if my device is reachable?
- Do each of them just have their own local copy of the folder that Google Drive just keeps in sync?

1: Or is the folder stored purely in Google Drive for the other people and only on my hard drive for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Google Drive, any change you make to the synced files on your computer
or on Google Drive will reflect on the other side too. Therefore:

- If your computer is disconnected from Google Drive, your
  colleagues can still work with files inside your folder and your
  computer will be updated when it is reconnected.
- If you're offline, your colleagues can still use your Google Drive.
- You have only one Google Drive folder in the cloud. Whether
  your colleagues have local copies or not depends on them and on
  whether they are syncing with your folder.